# Oracle Linux 6.5: Unable to install VLC 2.0.10 from rpmfusion-free-updates

Tags: vlc, oracle-linux

I want to install VLC in my Linux box. When I execute yum install vlc, it displays following message:-

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vlc.i686 0:2.0.10-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: vlc-core(x86-32) = 2.0.10-1.el6 for package: vlc-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libvlccore.so.5 for package: vlc-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcaca.so.0 for package: vlc-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: kde-filesystem for package: vlc-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libaa.so.1 for package: vlc-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package aalib-libs.i686 0:1.4.0-0.18.rc5.el6.1 will be installed
---> Package kde-filesystem.noarch 0:4-30.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libcaca.i686 0:0.99-0.9.beta16.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libglut.so.3 for package: libcaca-0.99-0.9.beta16.el6.i686
---> Package vlc-core.i686 0:2.0.10-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: live555date(x86-32) = 2012.04.27 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.120 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
Package x264-libs is obsoleted by x264, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53) for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
Package ffmpeg-libs is obsoleted by ffmpeg, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Processing Dependency: libtiger.so.5 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libzvbi.so.0 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.53 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
Package ffmpeg-libs is obsoleted by ffmpeg, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.51 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgme.so.0 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.53 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.51(LIBAVUTIL_51) for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.53(LIBAVCODEC_53) for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package freeglut.i686 0:2.6.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package game-music-emu.i686 0:0.5.5-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libavcodec53.i686 0:0.10.9-58.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxavs.so.1 for package: libavcodec53-0.10.9-58.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.136 for package: libavcodec53-0.10.9-58.el6.i686
---> Package libavformat53.i686 0:0.10.9-58.el6 will be installed
---> Package libavutil51.i686 0:1.0.8-58.el6 will be installed
---> Package libtiger.i686 0:0.3.4-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package live555.i686 0:0-0.34.2012.01.25.el6 will be updated
---> Package live555.i686 0:0-0.37.2012.04.27.el6 will be an update
---> Package vlc-core.i686 0:2.0.10-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.120 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
Package x264-libs is obsoleted by x264, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
---> Package zvbi.i686 0:0.2.33-6.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libx264_136.i686 0:0.136-19_20130917.2245.el6 will be installed
---> Package libxavs1.i686 0:0.1.51-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package vlc-core.i686 0:2.0.10-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.120 for package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686
Package x264-libs is obsoleted by x264, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)
           Available: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.9-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)
           Available: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)
           Available: libavformat53-0.8.15-55.el6.i686 (atrpms)
               libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)
           Available: libavformat53-0.9.3-56.el6.i686 (atrpms)
               libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)
           Available: libavformat53-0.10.9-58.el6.i686 (atrpms)
               libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)
           Available: ffmpeg-libs-0.6.5-2.el6.i686 (linuxtech-release)
               Not found
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libavcodec.so.53
           Available: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.9-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libavcodec.so.53
           Available: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.11-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libavcodec.so.53
           Available: libavcodec53-0.8.15-55.el6.i686 (atrpms)
               libavcodec.so.53
           Available: libavcodec53-0.9.3-56.el6.i686 (atrpms)
               libavcodec.so.53
           Available: libavcodec53-0.10.9-58.el6.i686 (atrpms)
               libavcodec.so.53
           Available: ffmpeg-libs-0.6.5-2.el6.i686 (linuxtech-release)
               Not found
Error: Package: vlc-core-2.0.10-1.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libx264.so.120
           Available: libx264_120-0.120-0.20120424.1.el6.i686 (linuxtech-release)
               libx264.so.120
           Available: x264-libs-0.120-4.20120303.el6_bootstrap.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libx264.so.120
           Available: x264-libs-0.120-5.20120303.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libx264.so.120
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. In my knowledge, if there are any dependencies, then package manager should find and install them too. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most immediate dependency not being found looks to be the 0.6.5 version of `ffmpeg-libs` which is usually something you would get from rpmfusion (which you appear to be using as well). rpmfusion, though, only goes up to v0.5 on RHEL/OEL 5, and jumped to v0.10 un RHEL/OEL6. So it's not able to locate that specific package version.

I'm seeing a lot of different repos popping up in that `yum install` command so it's possible that `yum` is pulling the a version of whatever specific package depends on `ffmpeg-libs` but that package is built against a version of `ffmpeg-libs` with a lower version number than any copy of that package in your repos has. So it's basically saying "I'm trying to install Package1 which needs version 0.6 of ffmpeg-libs, but out of all your repos the only thing I can find is version 0.10"

So you have two ways of solving these types of yum issues:

- Eliminate as many additional repos as you can. VLC is available in the RPM fusion repository which has worked well for me in the past. I don't believe they depend on any other repository existing besides the base repository for the core OS packages. I would try disabling all repos except whatever Oracle calls their base repo, EPEL, and rpmfusion itself and see if that causes the version numbers to sync up.
- Try to identify the repo causing that specific version of `ffmpeg-libs` to be required and check to see if the repo maintainers expect you to also have any other yum repos configured.

Of the two, the first one seems the easiest. You can do a `yum repolist` to see what repos you have installed and you can either disable them by editing their `/etc/yum.repos.d` configuration file, or added enough `--disablerepo=` options to your `yum install` command.

---

That said, you're going to have a hard time living with RHEL as a mutlimedia platform. I would recommend using Fedora or something like that and just running RHEL in a virtual machine or something. Fedora has a package called `virt-manager` that would allow you to do this. Do what you want, but it might be easier to use a system that was designed for desktop users as a part-time hypervisor than making a server OS behave like a desktop OS.